# How do you open multiple pages simultaneously with phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, headless-browser

I am using phantomjs as a headless browswer. I want to open two pages simultaneously which will then communicate via web sockets. Can I have both pages open at the same time within phantomjs and can phantomjs handle websockets? I am using socketio for the websockets. If phantomjs cannot support this I would appreciate being pointed towards a headless browser that can.

Comment: AFAIK, socket.io provides a fallback which works in PhantomJS 1.x. PhantomJS 2 should support WebSockets. You're asking two entirely different questions. Please reduce your "question" to only one question.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your main question:

> How do you open multiple pages simultaneously with phantomjs?

You have to launch multiple instances of PhantomJS at the same time.